# An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

The `post_install` used to work when I'd run `pod install` or `pod update`. But now it throws an error:

```
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

undefined method `push' for #<String:0x007f8726e2ee60>
Did you mean?  puts

/Users/waseefakhtar/Documents/iOS /Swift 3/Canary/Podfile:39:in `block (4 levels) in from_ruby'
/Users/waseefakhtar/Documents/iOS /Swift 3/Canary/Podfile:37:in `each'
/Users/waseefakhtar/Documents/iOS /Swift 3/Canary/Podfile:37:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
/Users/waseefakhtar/Documents/iOS /Swift 3/Canary/Podfile:36:in `each'
/Users/waseefakhtar/Documents/iOS /Swift 3/Canary/Podfile:36:in `block (2 levels) in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:179:in `post_install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:619:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:607:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:142:in `message'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:606:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:185:in `block in generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:182:in `generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:119:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/update.rb:81:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Here's my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'CanaryApp' do

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'PINRemoteImage'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
pod 'NSDate+TimeAgo'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
pod 'SSBouncyButton', '~> 1.0'
pod 'CSNPlaceholderTextView', '~> 0.0'
pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField'
pod 'Font-Awesome-Swift', '~> 1.6.2'
pod 'RSKGrowingTextView'
pod 'RSKPlaceholderTextView'
pod 'RSKKeyboardAnimationObserver'
pod 'SCLAlertView'
pod 'PureLayout'
pod 'RSKImageCropper'
pod 'SwiftSpinner'

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if target.name == "SkyFloatingLabelTextField"
                config.build_settings['LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS'].push('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator')
            end
        end
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'RSKPlaceholderTextView'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['$(inherited)', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator']
            end
        end
    end
end

target 'CanaryAppTests' do

end

target 'CanaryAppUITests' do

end
```

Comment: I don't know your code, let check your code in podfile because the error message very clear: **undefined method `push' for #<String:0x007f8726e2ee60>
Did you mean?  puts**

Comment: @Scott.N Updated OP with the entire code. But the problem seems to be only within the `post_install` block, is it not?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I'm having a similar issue on an M1 mac today. Would love to know what solved this.

Answer (score 1):

`run gem install xcodeproj`

`pod install` again

hope this will work for you...!